# Using nextLine() and nextInt() together in my context always gets an error

Tags: java, debugging, java.util.scanner

I'm writing some Java code that'll make a guessing game, where a random number is generated based on your maximum value and you have to guess the correct number. You can also set the amount of attempts you can get. This is where the problem occurs.

You see, you can set a number of attempts in number form or write out "unlimited". I have an example of the code that does this here with comments to help you out:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Game{

public static int processMaxAttempts;
public static Scanner maxAttempts;
public static String processMaxAttempts2;

public static void main(String args[]){
//Prints out text
System.out.println("Fill in your maximum attempts OR write \"unlimited\".");
//Creates a scanner
maxAttempts = new Scanner(System.in);
//Looks at the scanner "maxAttempts" and reads its integer value
processMaxAttempts = maxAttempts.nextInt();
//Looks at the scanner "maxAttempts" and reads its string value
processMaxAttempts2 = maxAttempts.nextLine();
//Prints out "unlimited" if "maxAttempts" has a string value and "set" if it has an integer value
if(processMaxAttempts2.equals("unlimited")){
System.out.println("unlimited");
}else{
System.out.println("set");
}//Close else
}//Close main method
}//Close class
```

What happens is a get an error that says this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:857)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1478)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2108)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2067)
at com.pixelparkour.windows.MainGameWindow.main(MainGameWindow.java:34)
```

That error targets this line of code:

```
processMaxAttempts = maxAttempts.nextInt();
```

So... yeah. I have no idea. I'm very new to Java (I've been learning it for only 3 days) and I'm a bit helpless. I'd love to know what my problem is so I can apply to it the future and program some cool games!

Comment: What input you are giving first time?

Comment: Please, post the content in `System.in` (what you're typing)

Comment: Sorry, I don't exactly understand what you mean. In my compiler it gives me a blank line that I can type in. A text input. Then I hit enter/return and it continues the code. As I said, I'm very new to Java :(

Comment: If you type "unlimited" in, then call `maxAttempts.nextInt()`, what do you expect to happen? You're telling it to read an `int`, but it finds a `String`, so your input doesn't match up to the expectation. You may want to consider changing your code so that, for instance, an input of `0` indicates unlimited attempts rather than mixing `String` and `int` inputs together.

Comment: So when do you enter the number that is your desired input? Do you directly press enter?

Comment: @JonK That was my mistake. I'll edit the post.

Comment: @shree.pat18 The code where it says "maxAttempts = new Scanner(System.in);" gives you a line that you can type on. Then yes, you press enter and it carries on with the following code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put a check on content type before reading the content.

What you need is :

```
if(maxAttempts.hasNextInt()){ // this will check if there is an integer to read from scanner 
       processMaxAttempts = maxAttempts.nextInt();
} else {
       processMaxAttempts2 = maxAttempts.nextLine();
}

if(processMaxAttempts2!=null && processMaxAttempts2.equals("unlimited")){
    System.out.println("unlimited");
}else{
    System.out.println("set");
}
```

Comment: Okay. Thank you. Just a couple of questions: one: what does "hasNextInt()" mean? Two: is the && thing meaning "also" or something else? I'm a newbie at Java, that's why I'm asking all these dumb questions.

Comment: No Problem @AnnualMelons, this will check if there is an integer to read from scanner or not

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
public class Test
{
private int guessableNumber;
private Integer maxAttempts;

public Test()
{
    maxAttempts = 0;
}

public void doYourStuff(){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random random = new Random();
    System.out.println("Please enter your amount of guesses or type unlimited for unlimited guesses");
    String s = scan.next();
    if(s.toUpperCase().equals("UNLIMITED")){
        guessableNumber = random.nextInt(100);
    }
    else {
        try{
            maxAttempts = Integer.parseInt(s);
            guessableNumber = random.nextInt(100) + Integer.parseInt(s);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("You did not enter a valid number for max attempts");
        }

    }
    int counter = 0;
    System.out.println("Type in a guess");
    while(scan.nextInt() != guessableNumber && counter <=maxAttempts){
        System.out.println("You did not guess correctly try again");
        ++counter;
    }
    if(counter > maxAttempts){
        System.out.println("You have exceeded your max attempts");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Correct you guessed the correct number: "+ guessableNumber);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Test test = new Test();
    test.doYourStuff();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

One little trick that always works for me is just going ahead and making a second scanner, i.e. num and text, that way you can always have one looking for int values and the other dealing with the Strings.